# Yii: File Upload Widget jquery.fineuploader [FineUploader] Caught exception in 'onComplete' callback - Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: exception, yii, fine-uploader

I have an existing source code. I have function called upload resource. If i click on upload button and try to upload image file it says following error.

> jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.min.js:4 [FineUploader] Caught exception in 'onComplete' callback - Cannot read property 'split' of null

In View file, Widget is added i.e. ext.EFineUploader.EFineUploader
Anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: The message indicates that there is an error in your `onComplete` callback function. Please post your code for further help.

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that there is an error in your [`onComplete` callback function](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete). You haven't posted your code, so there is no way to determine exactly where the error is, but it appears as if you are attempting to `split` a string, but the string in your code is null for some reason. You'll need to look closer at your code to determine where the error is.